# Docker Test Failing in Mac apple chip - Could not start a new session. Error while creating session with the driver service. Stopping driver service

Tags: php, docker, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, codeception

I have an existing test which runs fine in my old Mac intel chip. Now, I have a new Mac apple chip (M2) and need to get our existing tests to run using the new one.

I am relatively new with docker setup. My old Mac was setup with some set of instructions that I followed and pretty much did the same with the new Mac (except for installing the apple chip compatible app like docker).

But I hit the error below running the same test.
I could have miss some installation but not really sure.
Hoping to get some advise on this please.

```
  [Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\SessionNotCreatedException] Could not start a new session. Error while creating session with the driver service. Stopping driver service: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist 
Host info: host: '6e31c732ed28', ip: '172.30.0.7'
Build info: version: '4.10.0', revision: 'c14d967899'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.15.49-linuxkit-pr', java.version: '11.0.19'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Build info: version: '4.10.0', revision: 'c14d967899'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.15.49-linuxkit-pr', java.version: '11.0.19'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
#1  /opt/code/astute/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Exception/WebDriverException.php:125
#2  /opt/code/astute/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Remote/HttpCommandExecutor.php:371
#3  /opt/code/astute/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php:135
#4  Codeception\Subscriber\Module->before
#5  /opt/code/astute/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:184
#6  /opt/code/astute/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:46
#7  /opt/code/astute/module/test/lib/Command/Run.php:218
#8  /opt/code/astute/module/test/lib/Command/Run.php:328
#9  /opt/code/astute/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:255
#10 /opt/code/astute/cli/tests.php:47
```

Was able to bring up the Docker Container and looks ok as the existing API test are working fine in my new mac. Its only failing with the UI automated test

Comment: selenium is still not supporting arm64 architecture from scratch. there is an image in docker hub which is able to run selenium on arm called seleniarm which provides both architectures: https://hub.docker.com/r/seleniarm/standalone-chromium/tags

please share your docker compose file